# List all files of a particular type inside a directory on a remote machine in JAVA

Tags: java, file-io, https

I am trying to find a list of all zip files in a directory which is found by a path like:

```
https://abdc.defg.com/ijk/lmn/opq
```

If it was in a local filesystem, then the java.io.File's list() is does the job perfectly. But since this directory is on a remote machine in a foreign domain, java.io.File does not work. Even

```
File dir = new File("https://abdc.defg.com/ijk/lmn/opq");
```

does not work. I need a functionality just like java.io.File, and it would be best that I have to do this in Java's Standard APIs itself. Please suggest a way to do this like on a local file system:

```
File dir = new File("https://abdc.defg.com/ijk/lmn/opq");
File[] allFiles = dir.list();
```

Comment: Do you have access to that directory via HTTPS? It's not a normal filesystem.

Comment: Yes, I have a username and password. I have access to it.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I'm saying--what you're trying to do doesn't work like that. If you can FTP to the directory, that's one thing (but you'd still need to make FTP calls via a Java client).

Comment: I am working completely in Java. Actually, I am able to download a specific file inside this directory with a path like:
    https://abdc.defg.com/ijk/lmn/opq/rst.zip
I am using an Authenticator for username and password. But I need the name of all such .zip files inside this directory.

Comment: Yeah, and what I'm saying is, you won't get it, unless you can access it via something like an FTP client. Which you can do completely in Java. Or you parse the index page, which IMO is yucky.

Comment: Okay. The service that I am accessing has given me their https index. Can an ftp access be done to this same index, of course with due authentication. I'm sorry I a total greenhorn here, so pardon my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I don't know; I kind of doubt it. You could try via a command-line FTP client to find out, though.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but there is no way to do this with http(s) except the server offer some kind of service for this function, for example something like a index page that list all files in the directory.

Comment: I am not sure what an index page is, but the heading of this page in questions does read "Index of /ijk/lmn/opq". So I guess that makes it an index page. Yes, it is an index page I think.

Comment: @RaviKaran Then you can parse the HTML to get the info you need, although it seems very clunky.

Comment: @Ravi Karan: somethink like this: http://macdevcenter.com/mac/2003/02/04/graphics/sixtips7.jpg

Comment: Okay. But that would need to embark on a different approach altogether. I am trying to stick to plain old java. Although I will definitely try this if there is no way in Java.

Comment: Ravi Karan: I can not say clearer: there is no way, not for java or any other programming language. The problem is just that the protocol (http(s)) does not offer this function!

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks. Going ahead with this.